# Insertion of Comma

Tags: commas

What is correct?

Draw number 4 five times.

or

Draw number 4, five times.

Do we need to insert a comma between 4 and five? If the correct syntax is with a comma, is it because 4 and five are technically two numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Draw number 4 five times.

This is the more "correct" one.  In this case, it is similar to saying "hit me five times", where "hit me" and "draw number 4" are both actions.

> Draw number 4, five times.

This is not really proper English.  It is similar to saying "Draw number 4.  Five times."  This sounds like a rather informal, imperative command.